# NoSuchMethodEror: tried to call a non-function, such as null:

Tags: dart, flutter-web

I have this code which works well on android emulator but gives error on web.

```
import 'package:parivaar/components/screens/home/Home.dart';

typedef T Constructor<T>();

final Map<String, Constructor<Object>> _constructors =
    <String, Constructor<Object>>{};

void register<T>(Constructor<T> constructor) {
  _constructors[T.toString()] = constructor;
}

class ClassBuilder {
  static void registerClasses() {
    register<Home>(() => Home());
  }

  static dynamic fromString(String type) {
    return _constructors[type]();
  }
}
```

And i am calling that function as follows:

class _MyHomePageState extends State {
KFDrawerController _drawerController;

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _drawerController = KFDrawerController(
      initialPage: ClassBuilder.fromString('Home'),
.
..
...
....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably assuming that `T.toString()` returns the source name of the type as a string. Nobody ever promised that.
It works on native, but on the web you often optimize for *size* and "minification" turns all the long names into shorter names. With that, the name of the type `Home` is no longer the string `"Home"`.

I generally do not recommend depending on the string representation of types (or `Type`  objects for that matter).

Consider changing `register` and `fromString` to:

```dart
void register<T>(Constructor<T> constructor) {
  _constructors[T] = constructor;
}
```

and

```dart
  static T fromType<T>() => _constructors[T]();
```

That relies on `Type` object equality, which is a well-defined operation.
Not perfect, but still better than going through strings.

If you need to create the objects dynamically from *strings*, where you don't know the type, then I'd instead require you to provide the key string on registration, changing `register` to:

```dart
void register<T>(String key, Constructor<T> constructor) {
  _constructors[key] = constructor;
}
```

and register types like:

```
static void registerClasses() {
  register<Home>("Home", () => Home());
}
```